# C++ - converting an exe to source code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exe, netbeans-7

I have an appilication (.exe) i had created the code in Netbeans using c++ and generated this .exe is there a way to generate the corresponding code related to this .exe

Please provide an appropriate link to decompilers i am not able to figure those out.

Comment: It's called a decompiler.  Be prepared to wade through some really obscure code, since the compiled program may contain several compiler optimizations and none of the original identifiers will exist.

Comment: No, that is called *decompilation* and cannot work in general: an optimizing compiler is *loosing* a lot of information available in the source code, not in the binary

Comment: Even if you get the source code with random names for variables, you will spend more time figuring out what is going on that just to rewrite it from scratch.

Answer (score 5):

Not really.

You can use a [disassembler](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Analysis_Tools), or a [decompiler](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml), but it will not look like the original source code and it will require a lot of work to understand what is going on (variable names will be lost, for example).

You will get the best output if optimizations were disabled and debugging info was included when the source code was compiled.  Even then you might get something impossible to read.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no direct way.

Once source is compiled and specifically optimized any reference to it is in practice lost. You can disassemble it though, but you won't see any high level code.

Answer (score 1):

Use Hex-Rays Decompiler http://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml It converts executable programs into a human readable C-like pseudocode text